# Click event only working on one element?

Tags: jquery, events

I have wasted 1 hour on api.jquery.com and my script to identify the problem but still unable.

Here is my **script.js**

```
// DOM ready

$(function(){

    // gets categories from server
    $.post("category.php", function(data) {
        $("#category ul").html(data);
    });

    // tests click event
    $("a").click(function(evt) {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        evt.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

In index.php there are 4 anchor tags first three loaded from server as you can see in script and the last on is preloaded(static)(not loaded from server). Problem is that I have selected all anchor elements in jQuery selector as you can see in script but my event is only working with the last anchor tag which is pre-loaded. What is wrong ? Why the event is not working with the first three anchor tags ?

Comment: Because you are binding the event handler **before** the other `a` elements exist.

Comment: @FelixKling so how to overcome it ?

Comment: $(document).on('click','a',function(event){})

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772018/jquery-add-event-handler, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065329/jquery-adding-event-listeners-to-dynamically-added-elements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488861/automatically-add-an-event-handler-to-a-newly-created-element-using-jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `on`

```
   $('body').on('click', 'a', function(evt) {
     alert("Handler for .click() called.");
     evt.preventDefault();
   });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (){
    //do something
});
```

This will bind your handler to all anchor tags that currently exist and any that will be added dynamically in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

// gets categories from server
$.post("category.php", function(data) {
   $("#category ul").html(data);

// tests click event
   $("a").click(function(evt) {
      alert("Handler for .click() called.");
      evt.preventDefault();
  });
 });
});
```

you have to wait till the ajax post request is ready!

Greetings!