# Associate jquery callback when html change

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically add an event handler to a newly created element using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488861/automatically-add-an-event-handler-to-a-newly-created-element-using-jquery)

I need to associate a jquery callback on a dynamic content.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   $("#createContent").click(function(){
       $("#myCont").append('<img  class="myImg" src="icon.png"  />');

   });

});
</script>

<span id="createContent">click me</span>
<div id="myCont"></div>
```

If I click over "Click me", it add a image..well, now I want associate a JQuery callback at all the created images, but if I add this code in the .ready(), it doesn't work.

```
$(".myImg").click(function(){
       alert("click on img"); 
       $(this).remove();
} );
```

There is a way to associate a JQuery callback on runtime?

Here, there is the example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fM8Z7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
   $("#createContent").click(function(){
       $("#myCont").append('<img  class="myImg" title="blabla"  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mid-nights/santa/128/christmas-coupons-icon.png"  />');
       $(".myImg").eq(i).click(function() {
           $(this).fadeOut('slow');
       });
       i++;
   });              
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/fM8Z7/3/)

Comment: Could you please explain what your solution is and why it works?

Comment: But this calls the functiona so many times. If click the 6th image means it shows alert no of times. What's the reason for this

Comment: @Rithu: Because whenever a new image is created, a new event handler is bound to *every* existing `.myImg` element. This solution is not a good one.

Comment: Removing the alert doesn't change the fact that the handler is bound multiple times. It just sweeps the problem under a rug.

Comment: `.myImg` selects **all** elements with class `myImg`, doesn't it? How do you ensure that it only selects the newly created image?

Comment: yes. But how to achieve this without this issue

Comment: @Rithu: Get a reference to the created element and bind the event handler to it: `$('<img ... />').appendTo(...).click(...);`. Though event delegation is a better approach here IMO.

Comment: Yes appendTo is working fine. It doesn't bound the handler multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#createContent").click(function () {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('class', 'myImg');
    img.setAttribute('title', 'blabla');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mid-nights/santa/128/christmas-coupons-icon.png');

    img.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert("click on img");
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("#myCont").append(img);
});
```

This will create 1 `img` element, set it's properties, add an event listener, then append the image to `#myCont`.

Or pure jQuery:

```
$("#createContent").click(function () {

    var img = $('<img class="myImg" title="blabla" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mid-nights/santa/128/christmas-coupons-icon.png" />')
        .click(function () {
            alert("click on img");
            $(this).hide();
        }
    );
    $("#myCont").append(img);
});
```

Comment: If you have jQuery at your disposal, there is no need to use the plain DOM interface. While it's fine to use it to improve performance, in this case it just makes the code more verbose and `addEventListener` is not even cross-browser compatible...

Comment: @FelixKling: My second piece of code I edited in should work also, not?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

this append the element and initailize click to the appended element only

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $("#createContent").click(function(){
       var appendedItem= $('<img  class="myImg" title="blabla"  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mid-nights/santa/128/christmas-coupons-icon.png"  />');
      appendedItem.appendTo("#myCont")
                  .click(function(){
                      alert("click on img");
                      $(this).hide();        
                   } 
   );

  });
}) ;​
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fM8Z7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $("#createContent").click(function(){
   $("#myCont").append('<img  class="myImg" title="blabla"  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mid-nights/santa/128/christmas-coupons-icon.png"  />');  

} );
$("#myCont").on('click', function(event){
        alert("click on img");          
        $(event.target).hide();
   });
```

});​

Since the class ".myImg" doesn't exist when you bind the event, you have to bind the click event to an existing element. You can get the image which is clicked using the "event" object.

You can filter image tags using tagName attribute of event.target

Explore jquery event object for further data.

This method helps in avoiding multiple bindings.

Comment: What if `#myCont` also contains other elements besides the images?

Comment: You can hide only image tags using event.target.tagName

Answer (score 0):

This should do the magic:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
   $("#createContent").click(function(){
       $("#myCont").append('<img  class="myImg" title="blabla"  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mid-nights/santa/128/christmas-coupons-icon.png"  />');
       $(".myImg").eq(i).click(function() {
           $(this).fadeOut('slow');
       });
       i++;
   });              
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/fM8Z7/3/)